# Topic highlighted with different colors for different tags

Tags: support

Is there a way to have different colors for each tag or tag group?

For example, I would like questions tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) highlighted in orange, but questions tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) or [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) in yellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is nothing built in.

There appears to be a [User Script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3230/color-tags-script) that does that, however.

> This script allows you to colour tags for whatever reason you may have, i wrote it for fun after seeing a certain question on meta. The script adds a subsection called Color Mapping in the Favorite Tags section which allows you to adjust the colours.

Comment: It's good but not what i wanted. I would like the "background" of the questions to have different colors not the tag itself.

Comment: @DavideLettieri - You can search to see if there is such a user script, or write your own. There isn't such built in functionality (and I don't expect we will have it).